# Python - Elementtree - Search through tree using a variable

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have this xml file that has a lot of chemical groups and their properties. Here is a slice of the file:

```
 <groups>
  <group name='CH3'>
   <mw>15.03502</mw>
   <heatCapacity>
    <a>19.5</a>
   </heatCapacity>
  </group>
  <group name='CH2'>
   <mw>14.02708</mw>
   <heatCapacity>
    <a>-0.909</a>
   </heatCapacity>
  </group>
  <group name='COOH'>
   <mw>45.02</mw>
   <heatCapacity>
    <a>-24.1</a>
   </heatCapacity>
   </heatCapacity>
  </group>
  <group name='OH'>
   <mw>17.0073</mw>
   <heatCapacity>
    <a>25.7</a>
   </heatCapacity>
  </group>
<\groups>
```

In my python code that parses this file using ElementTree I have a list 
blocks=['CH3','CH2'] and I want to use this to find the two groups. I tried the following:

```
import elementtree.ElementTree as ET
document = ET.parse( 'groups.xml' )
blocks=['CH3','CH2']
for item in blocks:
   group1 = document.find(item)
   print group1
```

And all I get is 'None'. Can you please help me?

Many thanks

Comment: Perhaps it is worth to learn [xpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)...

Comment: in `lxml` you can just do `doc.xpath("//group[starts-with(@name,'CH')]")`, but I don't think elementtree has proper xpath support to handle that expression.

Comment: Is that your actual code? Because I'm used to seeing `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET` as the import statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find an element's attributes via its `.get()` method. Here is one way to look there:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
document = ET.parse( 'groups.xml' )
blocks=['CH3','CH2']
for group in document.getroot():
   if group.get('name') in blocks:
     print group
```

If you need access to the data through arbitrary selection criteria, you can create your own dictionary:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Parse
document = ET.parse( 'groups.xml' )

# Add a dictionary so that <group>s
# are easy to find by name
groups = {}
for group in document.getroot():
   groups[group.get('name')] = group

# Look up our compounds in the dictionary
blocks=['CH3', 'CH2']
for item in blocks:
    group = groups[item]
    mw = group.find('mw').text
    print item, mw
```

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for your reply. It is essential for me to iterate on my list because I want to get groups in the correct order.

Comment: Use a dictionary to store the group data in a convenient fashion. See my recent edit.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for block in blocks:
    group = document.find('./group[@name="{}"]'.format(block))
    if group:
        xml.etree.ElementTree.dump(group)
    else:
        print "Group {} not found.".format(group)
```

Comment: Hi Paulo thanks for your reply. I am using Python 2.4 which does not support this. How can I achieve this in 2.4?

Comment: replace `'./group[@name="{}"]'.format(block)` by `'./group[@name="%s"]' % block`

Comment: Sorry, I don't have 2.4 around in order to reproduce the problem. Update the question with the error message you got and I will be glad to help.